# Why is this query taking so long to execute?

Tags: mysql

I have this query below, and with just about 200k records in table, this query has started taking too long to execute. About 30 seconds or so.

I am not sure where or what is causing the problem.

I have other databases, with more than 2 million records, no issues of speed.

But somehow, for some reason, this query is causing problem on a site.

```
select p.pid, p.other_fields, c.user_name,
        group_concat( t.tag ) as tags 
from post_table as p, user_table as c, tag_table as t
where p.userID= c.userID 
and p.stat=1 
and p.mainID=0 
and c.stat='y' 
and  t.pid=p.pid 
group by p.pid 
order by p.pid desc 
limit 0, 20
```

This is the proper JOIN format of the same query, makes no difference, still slow.
This below is actually what I had earlier, but then changed it to the above older format, just to try if it makes any difference.

```
select p.pid, p.other_fields, c.user_name, group_concat( t.tag ) as tags 
from post_table as p
    LEFT JOIN user_table as c on p.userID = c.userID  
    LEFT JOIN tag_table as t on p.pid = t.pid 
where p.stat=1 
and p.mainID=0 
and c.stat='y'
group by p.pid 
order by p.pid desc 
limit 0, 20
```

Structures and indexes on these tables:

```
post_table:
pid, userID, stat, mainID, title, other_fields...
index( userID, stat, mainID, title )

User_table:
userID, stat, user_name, pass_word, etc...
index( user_name, pass_word )
index( stat )

tag_table:
id, pid, tag
index( pid, tag )
```

I think I am following all indexes properly, but still the query takes lot of time to execute, and I don't know why.

Can someone please tell me what could be the reason?
Thanks

Below is the output of the EXPLAIN statement of this query above:

But I am not sure what this is doing, however, I think that for some reason its ignoring the "stat" index on both user_table and post_table.

```
3 in array

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => SIMPLE
            [table] => c
            [type] => ALL
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY,id,id_2, userStat
            [key] => 
            [key_len] => 
            [ref] => 
            [rows] => 8
            [Extra] => Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => SIMPLE
            [table] => p
            [type] => ref
            [possible_keys] => PRIMARY,id,id_2, userID, postmainID
            [key] => userID
            [key_len] => 27
            [ref] => 
            [rows] => 15091
            [Extra] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => SIMPLE
            [table] => t
            [type] => ref
            [possible_keys] => pid
            [key] => pid
            [key_len] => 777
            [ref] => 
            [rows] => 1
            [Extra] => Using where; Using index
        )

)
```

Comment: I earlier had a proper left join statement itself, but that made no difference. Wait, I will edit the post to include that format as well. Makes no difference

Comment: If you have, in your where clause, `p.stat=1 and p.mainID=0` then it might make sense to create and index on those fields, otherwise mysql has to search te complete table to just find the records where this is true.  2nd: `c.stat='y': Because of this it is of no use doing an `LEFT JOIN`, because the missing records from `user_table` never meet this condition.

Comment: Hi @luuk I added the output of the EXPLAIN statement, but I am not sure what its doing... There is already index on "stat" in both user_table and post_table, but for some reason the query is ignoring them both.

Comment: Luuk, so how do I solve this issue? Could you please tell me what to do? Thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I think you mean "cross join".  Some of the `WHERE` clauses turn it into `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  p.pid, p.other_fields, c.user_name,
        ( SELECT group_concat( t.tag ) FROM tag_table AS t
              WHERE t.pid = p.pid ) as tags
    FROM  post_table as p
    JOIN  user_table as c  ON p.userID = c.userID
    where  p.stat = 1
      and  p.mainID = 0
      and  c.stat = 'y'
    order by  p.pid desc
    limit  0, 20

p:  INDEX(stat, mainID, pid, userID,  other_fields)
c:  INDEX(userID, stat,  user_name)
t:  INDEX(pid,  tag)
```

The `GROUP BY p.pid` is probably redundant now, put it back in if you need it.

There is no *performance* difference between the old comma-join and the new `JOIN..ON`.  There is a possible *semantic* difference between `JOIN`/comma-join and `LEFT JOIN`.  My reformulation for `tags` is equivalent to `LEFT JOIN`.  The existence of `c.stat = ...` forces the other `LEFT JOIN` to turn into `JOIN`, so no semantic difference.

`pid` is key_len=777?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so I can understand.  Ditto for `userID` and 27.

There are a lot of *possible* reasons for the Optimizer to avoid a given index.  It will probably use my indexes in preference to all others.

Comment: This change made very little difference, but when I used your query and also did this change:      "JOIN  user_table as c  ON p.userID = c.userID and c.stat='y' " then the execution time got cut down to half. Removed the c.stat='y' check from the where clause, and added it at the time of join itself as additional join condition. Its still overall very slow, takes  12-15 seconds or more, but is certainly better than original query. If I could speed it up little bit more then it would be much useful.

Comment: @SumitKumar - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.